# Required attribute to be shown visually

Tags: javascript, html, forms, polymer

I have a form where some fields are required, and some others aren't.
Now:

- Does Polymer provide any "out-of-the-box" way to mark an element as "required"?
- If not, what's the best way, in CSS, to show that a field is required?

At the moment, once the form is submitted the required fields will be shown as such. However, this happens *after* the form is submitted (or attempted).
I would like the user to know that while the first name is required, the middle name isn't.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use attribute `prefix` or `suffix`

```
<paper-input label="First Name">
  <div prefix>*</div>
  <div suffix>*</div>
</paper-input>
```

Another way would be to create a `new input element`

```
<span hidden={{!required}} class="required"> * </span>
<paper-input-container no-label-float="[[noLabelFloat]]" 
                       always-float-label="[[_computeAlwaysFloatLabel(alwaysFloatLabel,placeholder)]]" 
                       auto-validate$="[[autoValidate]]" 
                       disabled$="[[disabled]]" 
                       invalid="[[invalid]]">
```

But this does not make sense only for `required` field as you will have to emulate/copy the complete `paper-input` code

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic example how I'm validating the inputs: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGQ0h9?p=preview)

On each input change call the validation method,

if it passes - submit the form.

```
<paper-input  
                id="step"
                type="number" 
                min="1" 
                max="10"
                value="{{value}}"
                editable

                required

                auto-validate="true"
                invalid="{{invalid}}"
                preventInvalidInput
                error-message="value: {{value}}  - means invalid is {{invalid}}"

                on-change="stepChange">

</paper-input>



stepChange: function(e, detail) {

        //validation code
        //Fields must be revalidated on each change
        var step = this.$.step;
        var val_step = step.validate();

        // if alll the inputs are valid then submit the form
        if ( false == val_step )
          {
              console.log("not invalid");
          }
        else
          {
              console.log("invalid");
          }
},
```